# Not enough ram to run whole docker-compose stack

Tags: memory-management, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

Our microservice stack has now crept up to 15 small services for business logic like Auth, messaging, billing, etc. It's now getting to the point where a `docker-compose up` uses more ram than our devs have on their laptops.

It's not a crazy amount, about 4GB, but I regularly feel the pinch on my 8GB machine (thanks, Chrome).

There's app-level optimisations that we can be, and are, doing, sure, but eventually we are going to need an alternative strategy.

I see a two obvious options:

1. Use a big cloudy dev machine, perhaps provisioned with docker-machine and aws.
2. spinning up some machines into a shared dev cloud, like postgres and redis

These aren't very satisfactory, in (1),  local files aren't synced, making local dev a nightmare, and in (2) we can break each other's envs.

Help!

**Apendix I: output from docker stats**

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O
0ea1779dbb66        32.53%              137.9 MB / 8.186 GB   1.68%               46 kB / 29.4 kB       42 MB / 0 B
12e93d81027c        0.70%               376.1 MB / 8.186 GB   4.59%               297.7 kB / 243 kB     0 B / 1.921 MB
25f7be321716        34.40%              131.1 MB / 8.186 GB   1.60%               38.42 kB / 23.91 kB   39.64 MB / 0 B
26220cab1ded        0.00%               7.274 MB / 8.186 GB   0.09%               19.82 kB / 648 B      6.645 MB / 0 B
2db7ba96dc16        1.22%               51.29 MB / 8.186 GB   0.63%               10.41 kB / 578 B      28.79 MB / 0 B
3296e274be54        0.00%               4.854 MB / 8.186 GB   0.06%               20.07 kB / 1.862 kB   4.069 MB / 0 B
35911ee375fa        0.27%               12.87 MB / 8.186 GB   0.16%               29.16 kB / 6.861 kB   7.137 MB / 0 B
49eccc517040        37.31%              65.76 MB / 8.186 GB   0.80%               31.53 kB / 18.49 kB   36.27 MB / 0 B
6f23f114c44e        31.08%              86.5 MB / 8.186 GB    1.06%               37.25 kB / 29.28 kB   34.66 MB / 0 B
7a0731639e31        30.64%              66.21 MB / 8.186 GB   0.81%               31.1 kB / 19.39 kB    35.6 MB / 0 B
7ec2d73d3d97        0.00%               10.63 MB / 8.186 GB   0.13%               8.685 kB / 834 B      10.4 MB / 12.29 kB
855fd2c80bea        1.10%               46.88 MB / 8.186 GB   0.57%               23.39 kB / 2.423 kB   29.64 MB / 0 B
9993de237b9c        40.37%              170 MB / 8.186 GB     2.08%               19.75 kB / 1.461 kB   52.71 MB / 12.29 kB
a162fbf77c29        24.84%              128.6 MB / 8.186 GB   1.57%               59.82 kB / 54.46 kB   37.81 MB / 0 B
a7bf8b64d516        43.91%              106.1 MB / 8.186 GB   1.30%               46.33 kB / 31.36 kB   35 MB / 0 B
aae18e01b8bb        0.99%               44.16 MB / 8.186 GB   0.54%               7.066 kB / 578 B      28.12 MB / 0 B
bff9c9ee646d        35.43%              71.65 MB / 8.186 GB   0.88%               63.3 kB / 68.06 kB    45.53 MB / 0 B
ca86faedbd59        38.09%              104.9 MB / 8.186 GB   1.28%               31.84 kB / 18.71 kB   36.66 MB / 0 B
d666a1f3be5c        0.00%               9.286 MB / 8.186 GB   0.11%               19.51 kB / 648 B      6.621 MB / 0 B
ef2fa1bc6452        0.00%               7.254 MB / 8.186 GB   0.09%               19.88 kB / 648 B      6.645 MB / 0 B
f20529b47684        0.88%               41.66 MB / 8.186 GB   0.51%               12.45 kB / 648 B      23.96 MB / 0 B
```

Comment: Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Our low-hanging-fruit was `postgres`, by running
`ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections TO 1000`

Comment: To help your problem, we have to have more knowledge about your stack. Could you share what's all the 15 services are? And what's the configuration of each service? And what the memory footprints of each service?

Comment: 4GB sounds like a lot for 15 services. Your solution of altering postgres settings sounds like a good one. There are probably a few other things you can do to adjust the memory used by the services.

Comment: It was indeed the `postgres` that was chomping up all the ram. Most services are python-bases, flask or django, though we have a go and a scala service too. All these were using < 100MB each (the go was 4MB!), so I might answer my own question with the db advice.

Comment: But I leaves me worried, even with reasonably trim services, there comes a point where you might not be able to run it on a single laptop. Where do we go there? Answers in this vein would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have been struggling with this issue as well, and still don't really have an ideal solution.  However, we have two ideas that we are currently debating.

1. Run a "Dev" environment in the cloud, which is constantly updated with the master/latest version of every image as it is built.  Then each individual project can proxy to that environment in their docker-compose.yml file... so they are running THEIR service locally, but all the dependencies are remote.  An important part of this (from your question) is that you have shared dependencies like databases.  This should never be the case... never integrate across the database.  Each service should store its own data.
2. Each service is responsible for building a "mock" version of their app that can be used for local dev and medium level integration tests.  The mock versions shouldn't have dependencies, and should enable someone to only need a single layer from their service (the 3 or 4 mocks, instead of the 3 or 4 real services each with 3 or 4 of their own and so on).